# assigning multiple image urls to an item stored in sql server database

Tags: razor-pages

I am building an online shopping site using asp.net core razor pages, currently I have only one variable in my sql database table accepting a string as the image name but the image is stored in the root directory in images folder. This is my model

```
public class GasContainer
    {
        public int GasContainerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Weight { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public double Discount { get; set;}

        [NotMapped]
        public  double DiscountedPrice => Price - Discount;

        //public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public enum EColor
        {
            Red = 0,
            Yellow = 1,
            Green = 2,
            Blue = 3,
            Gray = 4
        };
        public string Type { get; set; }   

        public int?  BrandId { get; set; }
        public Brand Brand { get; set; }
    }
```

I want each gas container to have multiple image paths associated with it. How do I go about it since sql server does not accept an array as a data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how...
Add another table related to the GasContainer(one to many relationships) eg GasContainerImages table with imageurl property,  copy the uploaded files to a folder of your choice and update the  imageurl(s) of GasContainerImages with strings pointing to the folder with images